# Jasmine Get the page position - scrollTop() is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, karma-jasmine

I'm using jasmine and protractor to to do E2E tests for angularjs.

i want to test a menu, when clicking on the menu the page scroll itself, so i need to get the scroll top position of the body.

i created the following test:

```
it('Click on the menu, the page is scrolling', function() {
    var page_position = $('body').scrollTop();
    expect(page_position).toEqual(0);
    element(by.id('sub-menu-second')).click();
    page_position = $('body').scrollTop();
    expect(page_position).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

when i run the test i get:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'scrollTop'

not sure what i do wrong, please advise.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before you load your script? scrollTop won't work otherwise. If you are, could you give us a bit more of your code (like in a jsfiddle or something)?

Comment: js fiddle will be hard to give, but i think the problem is that i need to jasmine-jquery but i can't install it i get an error when i run it with npm -g install jasmine-jquery

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, you could use "document.body.scrollTop" instead of "$('body').scrollTop()".

Comment: i get "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: document.body.scrollTop should be executed in the context of the application running inside the browser using this.driver.executeScript()